# How to reduce size between cardview in android

Tags: android, android-cardview

first sorry or my bad English,how to reduce my card View size in android my card view size same as left margin and right margin size help me and how to place my text center like button

Here my  XML code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.001dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"

            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_nature"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="25dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:textColor="#24B9FE"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Test Test Test Test Test Test Test"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tv_nature"
        android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
        android:background="#24B9FE"
        android:text="Book"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

how to reduce my card View size in android my card view size same as left margin and right margin size help me

[image]

Comment: Can you show your `RecyclerView` xml?

Comment: I am using listView@Artur Szymanski

Comment: I reduced my size can u please tell how to place my textview center like as my book button

Comment: Are you using divider attributes in your `ListView`? I mean something like this: `android:divider="..."` or `android:dividerHeight="..."`

Comment: yes its working but how to place my text center like my Button@Artur Szymanski

Comment: You want to put your `TextView` (with texh "india") horizontally at the middle of your `CardView`?

Comment: i want to put my text same as my button my button right and center same like as my button left center@Artur Szymanski